# Fetch records that matches month and year using Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

How do I query a table such that it only fetches records that matches a particular month and year e.g. Y-m i.e. 2020-10. of the 'created_at' column.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
School::where('user_id', 1)->where('created_at', '=', '2020-10')->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a date range for your filter so this way your query will remain **[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)**

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($year."-".$month."-01");
$start = $date->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end = $date->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
School::where('user_id', 1)
      ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
      ->count();
```